# SqlQuery return null every time

Tags: c#, sql, datareader

I'm trying to execute a store procedure  like this:

```
public bool Test(){
    var searchItem=base.Database.SqlQuery<QueryEntity>("exec nameOfMyProcedure @param1={0}",param13).FirstOrDefault();
    if(searchItem!=null){
        return searchItem.Output1;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
private class QueryEntity{
    public bool Output1{get;set;}
}
```

I've one Return in the stored procedure

Unfortunately, searchItem always returns null.

Have you an idea how I can resolve that?

I'm using SQL server and C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution. 
It's not really proper but.. It's work

I create a new stored procedure which return 1 output like this

```
Select @Return_value as Return
```

instead of

```
Return @Return_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is returning more that one columns. That can be the reason for the error you are getting.

Comment: But the 'FirstOrDefault()' should fix that, or not(asking for my own knowledge)?

Comment: No, that will return the first element in the enumerable.

Comment: What does your stored procedure return?

Comment: @Alice - So modify the stored procedure so it only returns 1 bool?

Comment: So you need to change your code to accept both return parameters and then ignore the one you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
base.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<string>>("exec nameOfMyProcedure @param1={0},@param2={1},@param3={2}",param1,param2,param3)
```

basically this is an example and you need to do is, look into the structure of what your stored procedure returns and then use suitable object for parsing.

Here i am assuming all the returns values are string.

Comment: The output is two BIT so IEnumerable<bool>?

Comment: I tried and I have this: The result type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" may not be abstract and must include a default constructor